# Possible To Firing jQuery Base On Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is it possible to firing jQuery on a certain screen size?

In this case i need to run my script when the screen larger than 993px

here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  // scroll    
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.top');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.foo').css('transform', 'translate(0, -220px) scale(0.5)');
       } else {
          $('.foo').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0) scale(1)');
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current screen width easily with jQuery `$(window).width()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  if ($(window).width() > 993) {
  // scroll    
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.top');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top {
          $('.foo').css('transform', 'translate(0, -220px) scale(0.5)');
       } else {
          $('.foo').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0) scale(1)');
       }
   });
  }
});
```